# Can not run Emulator on Android Studio 3

Tags: android, android-emulator

When I run app on Android Emulator I am getting these log messages Any one have solution

```
Emulator: Could not launch 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator/qemu/windows-x86_64/qemu-system-i386.exe': No such file or directory

Emulator: [624]:ERROR:android/android-emu/android/qt/qt_setup.cpp:28:Qt library not found at C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\lib64\qt\lib
```

Comment: try to Create an emulator from AVD manager for your target API version

Comment: Welcome to SO. Updating the emulator will solve the issue I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

First Check if your system supports virtual devices and ensure that they are enabled

If it is supported then **To add it to the Android Studio installation, go to Tools->Android->SDK Manager, select the SDK Tools tab, then ensure that Android Emulator is selected.**

Answer (score 0):

go to Tools->Android->SDK Manager, select the SDK Tools tab, then ensure that Android Emulator is selected